# How to redirect a URL with a percentage (%) symbol?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, seo

I'm looking to redirect a couple of URLs with percentage (`%`) symbols in them to clean URLS. Example below...

Old URL:

```
http://www.testsite.co.uk/ecommerce/cabinets/white_gloss_cabinets/led_illuminated_white_cabinets%20/9101900.aspx
```

New URL:

```
http://www.testsite.co.uk/products/cabinets/austin/
```

Does anybody know the correct way to format a redirect for this in the .htaccess file? I'm using WordPress.

Thanks

Comment: maybe this can help you: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77257/how-to-redirect-urls-with-percent-encoded-characters-and-query-strings

Answer (score 0):

Try :

I replaced %20 with \s+ in the pattern.

```
RewriteEngine on



RewriteRule ^ecommerce/cabinets/white_gloss_cabinets/led_illuminated_white_cabinets\s+/9101900.aspx$ http://www.testsite.co.uk/products/cabinets/austin/ [NC,L,R]
```

In regex , %20 (a space) is matched using \s, or \s+ for 1 or more spaces.

Hope ,this helps!

Comment: Thanks Starken. I'll give a try. Just one thing... The brackets at the end, doesn't it need to include "R=301", so it would be [R=301,NC,L,R]

Comment: @Moclin **R** or **R=302** represent a temporary redirect , You can replace **R** with **R=301** to make the redirect permanent.

Comment: Thanks @starkeen ! It didn't work with the "s" so to get it working I simply used the \ followed by an empty space :)